# How to change cordova to phonegap in the development?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build

I developed mobile app using cordova cli but now i want to use phonegap instead of cordova to upload my app to the phonegap build. The mobile app which is developed by cordova having config.xml which is not in the 'www' folder.
        I heard that we can change cordova to phonegap with one line () in the config.xml but how can i run my app in local if i change the config.xml, it is giving errors?
        - Can any body please suggest me how to change from cordova to phonegap
        - How to upload into phonegap build

Comment: Can you just download the Phonegap project, create a new phonegap app using the documentation, and then copy/paste over your /www/ folder?

Comment: According to [Phonegap Build doc](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/configuring_basics.md.html) a config.xml for PhoneGap Build needs to have the line `xmlns:gap   = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"` in the XML widget definition, maybe that's what you mean?

Comment: yes you are right @qefzec, but i have to upload www folder which does not have config.xml